# Vertically center select inputs in table cell

Tags: css

I have a form that includes a table with select inputs in it. Currently the select inputs sit in the top of the cell. I would like the select inputs to be vertically centered.
This form is being generated in rails but the HTML and CSS being generated is the same as any other HTML/CSS form.

**rendered HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="business_contacts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title*</th>
            <th>First Name*</th>
            <th>Last Name*</th>
            <th>Ownership*</th>
            <th>Position*</th>
            <th>Employee*</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="fields" style="display: none;"> 
            <td>
                <select id="loan_application_business_contacts_attributes_1421767669447_prefix" name="loan_application[business_contacts_attributes][1421767669447][prefix]>
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=""></option>
                    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                    <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                    <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS (not working)**

```
#business_contacts select {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align it using td not select element itself:

```
#business_contacts td {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```